# set slower frame rate or longer duration for gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

when making animation from ggplot using gganimate, I need to set a lower pace to allow people to read data.

Reading documentation (hard to find options) seems that "nframes" is the proper setting. But I can't slow the animation or set the duration. Any of both approaches would be fine

```
library("gganimate")
library("tidyverse")

p <- ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp, color = Month)) +
  transition_time(Month) +
  labs(title = 'Month is {frame_time}') +
  geom_path(aes(group = Month), size = 1)

animate(p, nframes = 100)

Error in device(files[i], ...) : unused argument (nframes = 100)
```

Comment: Do you want the time-series to animate from month-to-month smoothly? I tried setting nframes = 500 and the animation is definitely slower but the frames are static when moving.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. Update your packages and start in a clean session?

Comment: I want the animation to take more time to finish, not get a bunch of static frames

Comment: Use the `fps` argument in your `animate()` call:  `animate(p, nframes = 300, fps=3)`  Increasing the number of frames and decreasing the fps will both accomplish what you are looking for.  If you are still getting that error, maybe try to uninstall and reinstall the gganimate package.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure why you received that error, but you can set the frame rate in the `animate()` function call:

```
animate(p, nframes = 100, fps=3)
```

Answer (score 5):

What helped me was the `duration` (in seconds) option, which in combination with `fps` (relates to smootheness of the animation) allows you to finely tune the length and smootheness of the animation:

```
animate(p, fps = 10, duration = 30)
```